# Error: "Function" not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I think this error is telling me that my insert function is not declared however as far as I can tell I have it declared correctly and it is in the public portion of my class so I think I should be able to use it in my main function. I'm trying to call it as just `insert(12);` however it's giving me Error: 'insert' was not declared in this scope.

```
class BST
{
    public:
        BST();
        BST(int* arr, int size);
        void insert(int val);
        void inOrderTraversal();
        void inOrderTraversal(node * Root);

    private:
        node * Root;

};

void BST::insert(int val) 
{
    node* temp = new node();
    temp->value = val;

    if(Root == NULL) {
        Root = temp;
        return;
    }

    node* current;
    current = Root;
    node* parent;
    parent = Root;
    current = (temp->value < current->value) ? (current->Left) : (current->Right);

    while(current != NULL) 
    {
        parent = current;
        current = (temp->value < current->value) ? (current->Left) : (current->Right);
    }

    if(temp->value < parent->value) {
        parent->Left = temp;
    }

    if(temp->value > parent->value) {
        parent->Right = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call it?

Comment: Add the part in your `main()` function where you included `insert(12)` to your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply writing `insert(12);` then you probably need to create an instance of your BST class and access it as a member function:

```
BST tree;
tree.insert(12);
```

Comment: @Garrett if this solved your issue, please mark it as so, thanks.